# Get request in Guzzle

Tags: php, get, guzzle

I am new to Guzzle and I am trying to get a request from my api

Here is what I have now:

```
  $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.harvestapp.com']);

  $request = $client->request('GET', '/v2/time_entries', [
    'headers' => [
      'Authorization' => 'Bearer bearer_key',
      'Harvest-Account-ID' => 'account_id_key']
  ]);
  $request = json_decode($request);
  return new JsonResponse($request);
}
```

I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: what are you getting errors?

Comment: I got a empty json back with only {} in it

Comment: Your API  `https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/time_entries` doesn't exist when I ran on browser, may be it's the cause that nothing returns from this, please check once API in browser.